# show that $\varphi : H \to H /N$ is one-to-one correspondence using kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I have a group G and subgroup N that is normal to G.
As a part of proving the 3rd isomorphism theorm (a version of it)
I need to prove that the transformation

from the subgroups of G containing N

that means from H such that $N \le H \le G$

to the subgroups of G/N (that means H/N)

$\varphi : H \to H /N$

is one-to-one correspondence.

What i did is I showed that ker($\varphi$) = N = $e_{H/N}$

is that ok ? in all the proves i see people are proving it differently..

any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Yes ! you are correct .

Comment: The elements of $\ker \varphi$ are elements of $H$, while $e_{H/N}$ is not an element of $H$. Do you mean $\varphi(h) = e_{H/N} \Leftrightarrow h \in N$?

Comment: it was an exam :) and i wrote it like that - $ker( \varphi) = (h \in H | hN = N) = (h \in H | h \in N) = N = e_{H/N}$ so it is one-to-one correspondence

Comment: is that a correct way to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like the correspondence $\varphi$ should not be going from a subgroup $H$ to a subgroup $H/N$.

The way you have it written $\varphi$ acts on the elements of $H$, so $\varphi(h)=(hN)$, but I think what the problem was asking you was to justify the injectivity of a map from the *set* of subgroups of $G$ containing $N$ to the *set* of subgroups of $G/N$, so $$ \varphi : \{H \leq G : N \leq H\} \to G/N \\ \varphi(H)=H/N$$

In general, this is not a group homomorphism, and proving that a function is injective by showing its kernel is trivial only works for functions that are homomorphisms. The statement of the theorem you used goes something like this:

If $\psi$ is a group homomorphism, then $\ker\psi =\{1\} \iff \psi$ is injective.

Since $\varphi$ is not a group homomorphism, you can't use that theorem, so to show $\varphi$ is injective, you need to use the definition: assume that $\psi(H_1/N)=\psi(H_2/N)$ and show this implies that $H_1=H_2$.

Comment: :( yep you are right. thanks for the answer

Comment: You're welcome :(. For what it's worth, what you wrote about the kernel being $N$ holds for the canonical projection: the group homomorphism $\pi : G \to G/N$ with $\pi(g)=gN$ has kernel $N$, and the proof goes as you wrote it.